# Conditionally apply pipe operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need a `timeout` operator to throw an error when parameter `isTimeoutNeeded` is True, so that I could handle the case if the subscribed observable do not emit any value after X seconds.

```
if (isTimeoutNeeded) {
    this.service.getData()
      .pipe(
          timeout(10000),
          ...
      )
      .subscribe((...) => ...);
} else {
    this.service.getData()
    .pipe( 
       ... 
    )    
    .subscribe((...) => ...);
}
```

Is it possible to write this in a rxjs way by conditionally adding `timeout` operator when needed?

I have tried using `iif` and `switchMap` but it did not work.

```
 this.service.getData()
    .pipe(
       mergeMap((response) =>
          iif(() => !isTimeoutNeeded,
          of(response),
          of(response).pipe(timeout(10000)) // did not apply timeout if isTimeoutNeeded = True
       )
    )
    .subscribe((...) => ...);
```

`switchMap`

```
 this.service.getData()
    .pipe(
           switchMap((response) => {
                if (!isTimeoutNeeded) {
                    return of(response);
                }
                return of(response).timeout(10000); // did not apply timeout if isTimeoutNeeded = True
            })
            .....
       )
    )
    .subscribe((...) => ...);
```

Comment: Not applying a timeout also means waiting for infinite amount of time for request to complete. So based on the value of isTimeoutNeeded you may manipulate the value of timeout. if isTimeoutNeeded is false, you may increase the timeout value and if it's true set it to 10s.

Comment: @emkay that's right. if isTimeoutNeeded = False, operator `timeout` will not be used in the pipe, hence infinite wait. This is the expected use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RXJS works best when the operators easily describe the behavior without detailing the implementation. When you start using `switchMap()` and conditions to *express* a behavior the intent gets lost, and the code becomes difficult to maintain.

So just write your own operator.

```
function timeoutWhen<T>(cond: boolean, value: number): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
   return function(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
       return cond ? source.pipe(timeout(value)) : source;
   }
}
```

Now when you use that operator the source code is easy to read and understand.

```
    this.service.getData().pipe(
       timeoutWhen(isTimeoutNeeded, 10000),
       ...
    ).subscribe((...) => ...);
```

Now you have something that is reusable and makes your observables easier to read and understand.

Comment: Nice and generic solution!

Answer (score 4):

You were almost right using `switchMap`:

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(this.service.getData());

subject
  .pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
      // If isTimeoutNeeded, a timetout is applied else wait result forever.
      return isTimeoutNeeded
        ? response.pipe(timeout(10000))
        : response;
    }),
    ...
  )
  .subscribe(... => ...);
```

In this code the timeout is applied on the `getData` observable whereas in your example it was a new observable.

Check my [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-y1bsfo).

Comment: it should be `of(response).pipe(...)`

Comment: @Reactgular as `getData()` returns an Observable, the response in the `switchMap` is an observable, no need to `of` operator.

Comment: Nope, what `subject` emits shouldn't be touched when you apply a timeout.

Answer (score 4):

For this particular case, I did it like this:

```
.pipe(
  (isTimeoutNeeded? interval(5000) : identity)
)
```

Comment: It's better to use *identity* function instead of tap() -
`import { identity } from 'rxjs'`
`isTimeoutNeeded ? timeout(10000) : identity`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RxJs pipeable operator [delayWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delaywhen.html):

> Delay emitted values determined by provided function.

Have it return an `interval()` observable like

```
.pipe(
  delayWhen(() => isTimeoutNeeded ? interval(5000) ? interval(0)
)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, however I need the `timeout` so that I could do something if the subscribed observable do not emit any value after X seconds.